# YouTube v3 API: Age restriction when uploading video

Tags: php, youtube

It's possible to set age restriction individually/manually via the Web UI, but it's not possible to set globally for a channel or account as far as I can see.

Is it possible to set via API when uploading a video?

The point is to avoid banning if I upload a video on behalf of another user, and I don't get time to screen the video.

Thanks in advance,

Anders

---

Update 1:

This is how I found I should do, according to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos:

```
$contentRating = new Google_Service_YouTube_ContentRating();
$contentRating->setYtRating('ytAgeRestricted');
$details = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoContentDetails();
$details->setContentRating($contentRating);
$video->setContentDetails($details);
```

Remarkably there's not a single example of use of Google_Service_YouTube_VideoContentDetails anywhere.

When this data is added to the video, the upload fails with the following. Clearly YouTube didn't like my setting. Is the use of age-restriction in itself restricted?

```
Google_Exception::__set_state(array(
'message' => 'Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 400: youtube.part, contentDetails)',
'string' => '',
'code' => 0,
'file' => '/home/u/u6554025/www/twitizer.com/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php',
'line' => 300,
```

---

Update 2:

That's a bummer if true:

http://gadgetsytecnologia.com/de585c5edb2f3a366/uploading-video-via-youtube-api.html

"You can read this property as: contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating = "ytAgeRestricted" but it looks like you can't POST this property in the video Resource in the body of your POST request to Youtube API"

Neither does the official documentation mention that insert supports contentRating.

Live and learn. Adopt, adapt, improve.

If anyone has any idea how to circumvent this, possibly with a global setting for the channel, I'm all ears.

Thanks,

Anders