# How to set age restrictions when uploading videos using YouTube API V3?

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

When using the YouTube V3 API to upload a video, does anyone know how I can set the age restriction to the video I'm uploading?

According to [this page](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/python/latest/youtube_v3.videos.html), the `ageGating` property is defined as follows:

```
"ageGating": { # Age restriction details related to a video. This data can only be retrieved by the video owner.
      "restricted": True or False, # Age-restricted trailers. For redband trailers and adult-rated video-games. Only users aged 18+ can view the content. The the field is true the content is restricted to viewers aged 18+. Otherwise The field won't be present.
      "alcoholContent": True or False, # Indicates whether or not the video has alcoholic beverage content. Only users of legal purchasing age in a particular country, as identified by ICAP, can view the content.
      "videoGameRating": "A String", # Video game rating, if any.
    },
```

I'm not sure what *redband trailers and adult-rated video-games* means exactly, but none of this seems to apply to my videos. I simply have some raw videos that could contain adult language or violence.

Does anyone know what should be set when using the API to upload videos?

I'm using C# and .NET. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352859/youtube-v3-api-age-restriction-when-uploading-video) but that's for PHP and I couldn't recognize the structures.

Comment: `"ytRating": "A String", # A rating that YouTube uses to identify age-restricted content.` - seems more like it, doesn’t it?

Comment: @RandRandom: Yes, it does. But it's a string. I don't know what to set it to.

Comment: well according to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos It should be `ytAgeRestricted`

Comment: @RandRandom: Ah, yes, I believe you're right.