# How to configure Age Restrictions, Comments, Ratings, and Customizations for YouTube Data API v3 and Live Streaming API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

##### Problem Details:

I want to utilize the YouTube Data API v3 and YouTube Live Streaming API to set up and create live streaming. However, despite going through the documentation, I haven't identified clear methodologies to configure the following settings:

- Age restriction (advanced)
- Comments and Ratings
- Customization (Live Chat, Participant Modes, Reactions)

**Details:**

1. **Age restriction (advanced):**

   - Options:

     - Yes, restrict my video to viewers over 18
     - No, don't restrict my video to viewers over 18 only
2. **Comments and Ratings:**

   - Comments options:

     - Allow all comments
     - Hold potentially inappropriate comments for review

       - Enable/Disable ``Increase strictness''
     - Hold all comments for review
     - Disable comments
   - Sorting options:

     - Top
     - Newest
   - Like display options:

     - Enable/Disable ``Show how many viewers like this stream''

**Customization:**

1. **Live Chat:**

   - Options:

     - Enable/Disable ``live chat''
     - Enable/Disable ``live chat replay''
2. **Participant Modes:**

   - Options:

     - Anyone
     - Subscribers
     - Livecommentary (approved users)
3. **Reactions:**

   - Options:

     - Enable/Disable ``Live reactions''

##### What I Tried and What I Was Expecting:

Regarding comment settings, I'm aware of issues in the configuration, as shown in the below issue tracker, such as the lack of official support for specific functionalities. I looked for documentation and examples on how to manage these settings through the APIs mentioned but found none that directly addressed my needs. I expected to find straightforward documentation or API methods that would allow me to configure these specific settings for live streaming.

**Issue Trackers Referenced:**

- [Issue Tracker 1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35174729)
- [Issue Tracker 2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35175046)

Could anyone offer guidance or point me to the relevant documentation or examples for managing these settings in YouTube live streaming via the APIs mentioned?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Divide and conquer* - please focus on one action *at the time* and you might have some results. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73396563/4092887) about how to set the age restriction to the video - I believe it applies for livestreams as well. Unfortunately, YouTube documentation is not *that* helpfull for specific actions with their API, so, search here on Stack Overflow and see if there are any code samples you can try.